# Are Apache Realms secure?

Tags: linux, apache, security

I have been told by our senior developer that Apache Realms (using either .htaccess files or the httpd config) are insecure and therefore bad practise to use in any sort of admin backend system. Is this true?

The way I see it, people cant see any .htxxx files under apache anyway, so how else can someone get around a Realm? Of course if they're inside your sever then they can do as they please, but at this point any security is insecure anyway, right?

Are there anyways of hacking or bypassing a Realm? Are they insecure to use?

If so, examples would be useful.

Comment: Ask your senior developer to elaborate. I don't think there is anything wrong with Apache Realms. You may want to use HTTPS for authenticated pages, though.

Comment: What did they tell you to use instead?

Comment: If you are not in position to ask question, do as your senior want, with appropriate comments in the code about your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some general weaknesses of http basic authentication, in no particular order and with no particular endorsement of them.

- using apache as your security layer means ops people are responsible for a critical layer instead of developers.  This might mean bypassing code reviews and other measures, depending on your departments' setup.
- using realms means you are vulnerable to various well known attacks, whereas a custom login php solution might be more obscure and less likely to be probed for.  (maybe)
- apache realms rely on specific well known files with well known formats, meaning any flaw involving adding or editing files to the system might compromise your login
- apache realms may also be attacked thru shell commands, meaning any flaw involving exec or system might compromise your login
- apache realms are vulnerable to brute force attacks, as they do not support captcha, or rate limiting
- theft of your password file means a potential compromise of all your passwords, which may cause a lot of headaches if you have a lot of users.
- having a sensitive password file might complicate deployment, backup, etc etc

All of the above issues are dealable, and as with most security arguments there are probably right answers, most likely your senior dev has numerous reasons you are not privy to.

Comment: Thanks. Explained perfectly :)